# Having issue with deployment to Herolu with react and Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I managed to get a build to succeed to heroku using react, node and graphQL but not seeeing the app in browser. When I run "heroku logs --tail" I get...

```
State changed from crashed to starting
2018-09-13T19:44:49.433722+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-09-13T19:44:53.370636+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-09-13T19:44:53.370683+00:00 app[web.1]: > Workout_JS@1.0.0 start /app
2018-09-13T19:44:53.370685+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "cd client && PORT=3000 npm start" "cd server && PORT=5000 npm app.js"
2018-09-13T19:44:53.370687+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077898+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077919+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Usage: npm <command>
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077921+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077922+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] where <command> is one of:
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077927+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     access, adduser, bin, bugs, c, cache, completion, config,
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077930+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor, edit,
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077932+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     explore, get, help, help-search, i, init, install,
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077933+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     install-test, it, link, list, ln, login, logout, ls,
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077934+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix, prune, publish, rb,
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077936+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     rebuild, repo, restart, root, run, run-script, s, se,
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077938+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     search, set, shrinkwrap, star, stars, start, stop, t, team,
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077939+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     test, tst, un, uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update,v,
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077940+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     version, view, whoami
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077943+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm <command> -h     quick help on <command>
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077942+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077946+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm -l           display full usage info
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077947+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077949+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm help npm     involved overview
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077951+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077952+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077953+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     /app/.npmrc
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077955+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077956+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Config info can be viewed via: npm help config
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077958+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2018-09-13T19:44:57.077959+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm@5.3.0 /app/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm
2018-09-13T19:44:57.095023+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] cd server && PORT=5000 npm app.js exited with code 1
2018-09-13T19:44:57.330192+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
2018-09-13T19:44:57.330203+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > client@0.1.0 start /app/client
2018-09-13T19:44:57.330205+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > react-scripts start
2018-09-13T19:44:57.330207+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
2018-09-13T19:45:04.225951+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] Starting the development server...
2018-09-13T19:45:04.225966+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
2018-09-13T19:45:29.117989+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] Compiled with warnings.
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118003+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118005+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] ./src/components/Modal.js
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118007+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]   Line 11:  Unreachable code  no-unreachable
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118009+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]   Line 14:  Unreachable code  no-unreachable
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118011+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118013+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] ./src/components/Timer.js
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118016+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118015+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]   Line 30:  'run' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118020+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]   Line 40:  'movements' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118018+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] ./src/components/Push.js
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118022+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118023+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] ./src/components/Length.js
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118025+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]   Line 47:  Expected to return a value in arrow function    array-callback-return
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118029+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]   Line 54:  'movements' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118036+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118030+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118027+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]   Line 53:  'wods' is assigned a value but never used       no-unused-vars
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118034+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
2018-09-13T19:45:29.118032+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
2018-09-13T19:45:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user brad.hankee@gmail.com
2018-09-13T19:45:50.123072+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-09-13T19:45:50.123205+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-09-13T19:45:50.297808+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-09-13T19:45:50.282015+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-09-13T19:46:40.674676+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=workout-js.herokuapp.com request_id=fea7a8cf-f60f-47dc-9d8f-e3a6447de8b1 fwd="98.166.56.134" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-09-13T19:46:40.879839+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=workout-js.herokuapp.com request_id=00bd54f8-ccfa-410a-9719-36adfcca38b8 fwd="98.166.56.134" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-09-13T19:46:42.370752+00:00 app[api]: Deploy daef049a by user brad.hankee@gmail.com
2018-09-13T19:46:42.370752+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user brad.hankee@gmail.com
2018-09-13T19:46:43.950807+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-09-13T19:46:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-09-13T19:46:51.564733+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-09-13T19:46:54.322782+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-09-13T19:46:54.244449+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-09-13T19:46:54.244488+00:00 app[web.1]: > Workout_JS@1.0.0 start /app
2018-09-13T19:46:54.244490+00:00 app[web.1]: > cd server npm app.js
2018-09-13T19:46:54.244492+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-09-13T19:46:54.304960+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

Using concurrently to run in dev but not sure how to set up script for heroku... my file structure is...

app
-client
-- package.json
-server
-- package.json
package.json

here are my three package.jsons in detail ...

CLIENT

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.2.0"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reach/router": "^1.1.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.1.14",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-apollo": "^2.1.11",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

SERVER

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.2.0"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-graphql": "^0.6.12",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.9"
  }
}
```

ROOT

```
{
  "name": "Workout_JS",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.2.0"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "cd server npm app.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/bhankee/Workout.js.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/bhankee/Workout.js/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/bhankee/Workout.js#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

Thanks  also I did use this is the root package .json but no luck

```
"start": "concurrently \"cd client && PORT=3000 npm start\" \"cd server && PORT=5000 npm app.js\"",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have your app bind to `$PORT`. Right now, you appear to be binding to 5000. As a result, you're getting this error:

`2018-09-13T19:45:50.123072+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

Here's some more info: https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error

Comment: I do have this in my app.js which is my server...
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
     //allow cross-origin requests
    app.use(cors());

You mean I have to do that for the proxy too?

Comment: This log line tells me your app is trying to boot on 5000: `PORT=5000 npm app.js`